# send Javascript variable to .css({transform: translate (var,var)})

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanted to move a div 136px to right with transform property so i wrote:
`

```
$(".the_div").css({"transform":"translate(136px,0px)"});
```

and the_div class contains

```
.the_div
{
  transition-duration:2s;
}
```

and it worked but now i want to send a javascript variable instead of 136px.
is that possible? how can i do that?
a variable like

```
var my_width = window.innerwidth * 0.1;
```

i wrote

```
$(".the_div").css({"transform":"translate(my_width+'px',0px)"});
```

and it obviously didnt work.
do you have an idea to move a div One-tenth of screen width to right (using transform property)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply you just need concatenate variable in string in javascript  `" + my_width + "`

```
$(".the_div").css({"transform":"translate(" + my_width + "px,0px)"});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in pure Javascript as well using template strings.
(PS - you don't even need JQuery)

First, save **the div** in a variable

```
const theDiv = document.querySelector('.the_div');
```

Second, save **the value** you want to translate in a variable

```
let number = 136;
```

Lastly, set **the style** attribute of the div

```
theDiv.style.transform = `tranlate(${number}px,0)`;
```

Hope this helps answer your question

Here is a helpful link for template strings
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals